# Excel Won't Insert Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that won't allow me to insert a new column.  It is a Macro enabled workbook which I believe is the cause of the issue.   When I insert a new column nothing happens except an activeX button on the page moves to the right.   How can I fix this??

Here is a gif of what is happening. Notice in the top right corner the button moves to the right with each insert

[image: Insert Error GIF]

The macro is a loop that sorts a data range from highest to lowest turn rate, and adds a unit of discretionary allocation until there is none left to distribute. simplified snippet:

```
 Sub SecondaryDistrLoop()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Set variables

    'Calculate the worksheet to ensure all formulas are up to date
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    'get secondary allocation amount to distribute
    AmountToDistribute = Range("Q2")

    'get address of title cell where secondary allocaton goes (TITLED: Natl Reserve Discretionary)
     Cells.Find(What:="Natl Reserve Discretionary", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Set AllocationAdjustmentTitleCell = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell)


    'get address of Dec Turn Rate column to sort on
    Cells.Find(What:="Dec Turn Rate", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    'get address of title cell for sorting column TITLE: (New DS on 3 Mth Avg Sales)
    SortColumnAddressString = ActiveCell.Address(Rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)
    SortColumnReferenceString = Left(SortColumnAddressString, 1)
    ChartTitleRowNumber = Right(SortColumnAddressString, 1)



    'Find Range of dealers to be sorted - aka finding range until the national summary rows
    Cells.Find(What:="Code", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    LastRow = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row - 1
    LastColumn = ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column + 17


    Set DataRange = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))


    AllocationAdjustmentTitleCell.Activate

    'start loop
    Do Until AmountToDistribute = 0



    'update formulas
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    'Sort data to bring highest days supply to the top of list - range is built of dynamically finding column name New DS on 3 mth avg sales
    DataRange.Sort key1:=Range(SortColumnReferenceString & ChartTitleRowNumber + 1 & ":" & SortColumnReferenceString & LastRow), _
       order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

    'set lowest days supply to increase secondary allocation by 1
    AllocationAdjustmentTitleCell.Offset(1, 0) = AllocationAdjustmentTitleCell.Offset(1, 0).Value + 1

    'reduce the amount to distribute by 1
    AmountToDistribute = AmountToDistribute - 1



    Loop


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I assume your not out of columns. Excel 2010 allows 16,384. Are there hidden columns to the left of that column. Could it be inserting hidden columns?

Comment: @MatthewD Nope.....Only using up to column T.....  The entire workbook is acting like this.  No columns to unhide.  I can keep clicking insert column, just keeps pushing the button further out to the right

Comment: in your code, are you doing anything like Application.EnableEvents = False?

Comment: Is the sheet protected? Have you looked at the VBA code? What code is there in the sheet module? Did you try understanding it or fixing it in any way? Please, something to help us help you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett  please see my code snippet.   I'm just running a loop that sorts data after recalculating.

Comment: Well something is happening... the button keeps moving

Answer (score 0):

Working with the file from a network location was the issue.  I brought the file down on to my local drive and it was all fixed......dazed and confused